# (Play 2.4) Dependency injection in a trait?

Tags: scala, playframework, dependency-injection, guice

In play 2.4, is it possible to use dependency injection in a trait ?

Is there any example ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I talk about runtime DI with Guice here because it's the default method used by Play. Other DI methods or frameworks may differ here.

It isn't possible to inject a dependency into a trait because a trait isn't instantiable. A trait doesn't have a constructor to define the dependencies.

In Play you could use the injector directly as long as the [Application](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/fa5785bf6b464d9ca58aabed5a3e351be545b666/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Application.scala#L214) trait is in scope. But this isn't considered good practice in production code. In test code this would be an option.

```
class MySpec extends PlaySpecification {
  "My test" should {
    "Use the injector" in new WithApplication extends Context {
      val messages = Messages(Lang("en-US"), messagesApi)
    } 
  }

  trait Context extends Scope {
    self: WithApplication =>

    val messagesApi = app.injector.instanceOf[MessagesApi]
  }
}
```

Comment: So in production code, what *is* the good, recommended way, for example when you need to use "AuthService" in a "Secured" trait: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34223440/56285